# Comparing value from html to context

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need to compare a value (variable) extracted from a page to context.

For example:

Color is a dropdown selection.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#color").change(function() {
        var selected_color = $(this).val() ;
        {% if context_value == selected_color %}
           .. do something
        {% endif %}
})};
```

Is this possible ? If not, is there some solution for such case ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use Ajax to communicate asynchronously between JavaScript and python (without refreshing the page).

your JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#color").change(function() {
        var selected_color = $(this).val() ;
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'color_check',
            data: selected_color,
            success: handleFormSuccess,
            error: handleFormError,
        })
})
function handleFormSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
.. do something
}
function handleFormError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}
};
```

Your python view:

```
def color_check(request):
  if request.is_ajax():
    selected_color = request.POST
    context_value = 'Red'
      if selected_color == context_value:
        return JsonResponse(True)
```

EDIT: Arun Singh's solution is simpler and works too. I would only make the paragraph hidden from the user:

```
<p style="display:none" id="my-data" data-name="{{context_value}}"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id='data'>{{ context_value }}</p>
  or
<p id="my-data" data-name="{{context_value}}"></p>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#color").change(function() {
    var selected_color = $(this).val() ;
    var djangoData = $('#data').val();
    if (djangoData === selected_color){
        console.log('do something)
    }else{
        console.log('do something else') 
    }
```

})};